# I'm using a coroutine and the code is stopping at yield return without resuming after the given time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a script I'm attaching to a button in order to load the next level when clicked

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class LoadNextLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    static Action<string> LoadNextLvl;
    void Start()
    {
        //The issue isn't with the delegate because i tried running the 
        //code without it
        LoadNextLvl += (string name) => StartCoroutine("LoadFunc" , name);
    }
    IEnumerator LoadFunc(string name)
    {
        //This is to load the next level, it has nothing to do with the bug
        int levelnum = int.Parse(name[5].ToString());
        levelnum++;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading");
        //i want to wait for a certain amount of time then load the next scene
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        //For some reason the code stops here and doesn't continue even after
        //I wait, in fact I tried yield return null but the same issue still
        //occurs.
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level" + levelnum);

    }
    public void Load()
    {
        //This function will be called using a button
        LoadNextLvl(gameObject.scene.name);
    }
}
```

As I explained in the comments, I tried different things until i narrowed down the issue to the fact that it stops at yield return even though I did exactly like all the tutorials I found.

Comment: Also, if timescale is set to 0, unless you use `WaitForSecondsRealtime()` 2 seconds will take forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading");
```

the current scene is unloaded and this component most probably along with it so your Coroutine is only executed to the first `yield` and then never continues.

Also you really don't need that delegate. Why not simply call your method directly like this:

```
public class LoadNextLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator LoadFunc()
    {
        var levelnum = int.Parse(gameObject.scene.name[5].ToString());
        levelnum++;
        // Make sure this is not destroyed when the scene is unloaded
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Loading");
        
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level" + levelnum);

        // Then once you don't need this anymore now destroy it
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadFunc());
    }
}
```

Instead of going by strings you could also use

```
var nextIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;
```

and then later

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(nextIndex);
```